# Chamilo login with facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, chamilo-lms

I'm developing an e-learning site using the Chamilo LMS platform (version  1.10.2). I have trouble integrating the functionality of login with facebook.

Chamilo and comes with a plugin to activate to achieve this functionality, but it does not work.

According to the configuration of the plugin, add the appID and appSecret in the file [auth.conf.php](https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/blob/1.10.x/app/config/auth.conf.dist.php)

When I click to Facebook icon on the login page Chamilo It Takes to be the Facebook Login eleven logged into facebook, it redirects the user back to Chamilo but the user is not logged in nor registered. Any ideas?

You can test [here](http://foeponline.net/).

For reference I leave the links (from github) to plugin files and settings.

- [Facebook SDK in chamilo](https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/tree/master/main/auth/external_login)
- [Plugin files](https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/tree/master/plugin/add_shibboleth_login_button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and have solved.: https://support.chamilo.org/issues/8156

Answer (score 0):

Your fix has been applied to Chamilo 1.11.0, which has been released on the 17th of October 2016. You can download it from https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/releases